# chemnum: incorrect hyperlinking of compound sublabels

Tags: hyperref, chemistry, chemmacros, chemnum

I am using chemnum within the chemmacros package. When I use a compound with a sublabel, the hyperlink that is created only links to the first use of the **main** label (1) instead of the actual compound (i.e. 1b):

[image: screenshot]

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{upgreek} % required by chemmacros
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\setchemnum{hyperlinks=true} % chemnum package is loaded by chemmacros

\DeclareChemReactant{MeBenzIm_Se.DHP}{
    name={\iupac{\cis-6-me|thyl-2,3,4,4a,6,11a-hexa|hy|dro|ben|zo[4,5]imi|da|zo[2,1-\textit{b}]py|ra|no[2,3-\textit{d}][1,3]se|le|na|zol-11-ium}}
}
\DeclareChemReactant{MeBenzIm_Se.Cy}{
    name={\iupac{\cis-6-me|thyl-2,3,4,4a,6,11a-hexa|hy|dro-1\hydrogen-ben|zo[\textit{d}]ben|zo[4,5]imi|da|zo[2,1-\textit{b}][1,3]se|le|na|zol-11-ium}}
}

\usepackage{hyperref} % should be loaded last

\begin{document}

\reactant{MeBenzIm_Se.DHP} and \reactant{MeBenzIm_Se.Cy}.

\vspace{10mm}

\cmpd{MeBenzIm_Se.DHP} and \cmpd{MeBenzIm_Se.Cy}.

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I am not too familiar with the expl3 syntax, so I could not work out a workaround for myself.

Comment: always provide a small but complete example that can be used for a test.

Comment: Did you compile twice? In the first run Latex compiles references, in the second it resolves them. That's why references appear to be missing (not yet compiled) or wrong (not yet updated).

Comment: I am compiling with latexmk using the latex-workshop vs code extension. I can compile many times, however, this does not resolve the issue. I believe the code is running correctly, but the feature is just not implemented as of now.

Comment: Yes, got the same observation. However, chaning all MeBenzIm_Se.Cy into MeBenzIm_Sem.Cy for a try make both links "disappear" ...